# Can some one tell me how to make the function run once and then end?

Tags: javascript, shopify, redirect-loop

I'm a total newb when it comes to stack please forgive me I have googled over and over and read several threads on stack on how others stopped a redirect loop however, the issue I have from what I have read is I need this page to redirect to same URL + /universal which as I understand is the reason for the loop. I tried the code for checking the url but it did not stop the loop.

```
$(window).load(function() {
url = "{{ collection.url }}/universal";
$( location ).attr("href", url);
});
```

Comment: is it the same code running? you could just check if you're already at /universal and if so, don't redirect

Comment: Maybe you should make an if-statement and check if the URL already contains the "/universal" part?

Comment: You could try `$(window).one('load', fn).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make an if-statement and check if the URL already contains the "/universal" part, something like

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf('/universal') < 0){
    url = "{{ collection.url }}/universal";
    $( location ).attr("href", url);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @UberGrunk This work perfectly! the other redirect checks I used previously did not.